Should keys-size be renamed to key-size?
We have the key-size tag its synonym, key-length. However, there is another tag with a non-negligible number of uses called keys-size. Notice the extraneous s. Should this be renamed to key-size?

I've simply gone ahead and merged it with key-size, without creating a synonym. I don't think it warrants one because it is just a misspelling of sorts (probably some questions took this tag because they typed "keys" rather than "key" before looking for matches, or getting too many matches for just "key"). We can rinse and repeat if the tag re-emerges.
